# Does the equation $n^2+(n+1)^4=5(n+2)^3$ have a solution in positive integers?

Tags: number-theory

The LHS being the sum of two even functions is an even function. But the RHS is an odd function.
Does this imply that there will be no solution in positive integers?
If so, what is the significance of mentioning 'positive integers' in the question?

Comment: $n^2 = n$ is an even function on the LHS and an odd function on the RHS, yet it still has two solutions ($0$ and $1$). So that's not a way to argue for no solutions.

Comment: What you mentioned implies that LHS and RHS are different functions (as functions.) for example, $y =2x$ and $y = x^2$ are odd and even function respectively, but there is a (nonzero) solution for $x^2 = 2x$.

Comment: Also, there is close to no significance to specifying positive integers. It's pretty clear that for $n\leq -2$, there are no solutions just by looking at the signs of the LHS and RHS (here the even exponents on the LHS and the odd exponent in the RHS do help out greatly), so the significance is as big as checking by hand whether $n = -1$ and $n = 0$ are solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Open up all:

$$n^2+n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1=5(n^3+6n^2+12n+8)\implies$$

$$n^4-n^3-23n^2-56n-39=0\implies\;\text{the only possible natural root is from}\;\{1,3,13, 39\}$$

and now it's easy to check each case (even by approximation)...and none is

Comment: How are you getting that the only possible natural root is from {1,3,13}??

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem In the often occuring case that the factor of the leading coefficient is $1$ (as it is here for $n^4$) that means the root must be a divisor of $39$ and since only positive values are allowed, this is exactly the set DonAntonio gave.

Comment: @Ingix You are right in both things, though I should have added it. I edited that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the LHS nor the RHS are even or odd ! You should review the definition.

Had the LHS and RHS function different parities, only positive or negative solutions would be possible.

Had the LHS and RHS function the same parities, all solutions would come in pairs of opposite signs.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that works is to realize that the left hand side, being a poylnomial of degree 4 in $n$, increases faster than the right hand side, a polynomial of degree 3 in $n$. So starting from some point $N$, the left hand side will always be bigger than the right hand side when $n \ge N$. So only values less than $N$ need to be considered.

To find $N$, the original form of the equation is not well suited, so let's use the form when all parenthesis have been eliminated, as was done in the answer by DonAntonio:

$$n^4-n^3-23n^2-56n-39=0.$$

For $N=7$, we get, under the general assumption that $n \ge N$:

$$n^3 = \frac{n^4}n \le \frac{n^4}7$$

and similiarly

$$23n^2 \le \frac{23}{49}n^4,\; 56n \le \frac{56}{7\cdot49}n^4 = \frac{8}{49}n^4,\; 39 \le\frac{39}{49\cdot49}n^4 < \frac{1}{49}n^4.$$

That means

$$n^3+23n^2+56n+39 < \frac17n^4+\frac{23}{49}n^4+\frac{8}{49}n^4+\frac{1}{49}n^4=\frac{7+23+8+1}{49}n^4 = \frac{39}{49}n^4 < n^4.$$

That means for $n\ge 7$ the term $n^4-n^3-23n^2-56n-39$ can never be $0$, as it is always positive.

That means you only need to check $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ to find your solutions.

Compared with the solution by DonAntonio, that's more values to check. But generally, when the constant term of the equation (here: $39$) has more divisors, using both arguments together can lead to a decrease of values to check.

How did I arrive at $N=7$? Well, the term $23n^2$ means that the least $N$ to test is $N=5$, so we get $23n^2 = 23\frac{n^4}{n^2} \le \frac{23}{25}n^4$. Using $N=4$ leads to the correct but useless $23n^2 = 23\frac{n^4}{n^2} \le \frac{23}{16}n^4$, as $\frac{23}{16} > 1$ so the sum we made above where all coefficients before $n^4$ were summed will neber be $< 1$ this way, if already one summand is $> 1$.

So I started with $N=6$, but that turned out to also not work, and $N=7$ did.